# How to terminate SignalR Core call

Tags: signalr, signalr-hub, asp.net-core-signalr

When a user makes an error, e.g wrong input, what should I do to return an error to the client?
The documentation of `IHubFilter` it says:

> To skip a hub method invocation in a filter, throw an exception of type HubException instead of calling next. The client will receive an error if it was expecting a result.

I tried that but this is an unhanded exception that's caught by the debugger. So I don't think this is the right way of doing this.

Comment: Are you talking about CancellationToken behaviour?

Comment: I just want to send an error response to the client, I don't care about the mechanism.

Comment: They you just need to catch the exception and broadcast an error message to the client.

Comment: Look at the answer please, do you mean that?

Answer (score 0):

Okay, It's more clear now.

We can catch `HubException` and your own different derivatives like `BadInputException: HubException` and handle it by returning a new `ValueTask<object>` with the error message or the exception it self.

But put in mind that these exceptions are not handled unless they are RPC calls not internal system call like timer callback.

That what I concluded so far, there may different approachs for this.

Comment: This way doesn't work in the client I use, it require custom unnatural way of calling, and doesn't return a failed task. Does anyone has a better way?